# "GvrController" does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, daydream

Why may this error appear?

> error CS0103: The name `GvrController' does not exist in the current
>   context

I'm working with the Daydream Unity project which was developed by another person, after opening it I see this error everywhere, where the GvrController is referred to.

It feels like the reason is something simple, what could it be?

Comment: `https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/reference/class/gvr-controller`